# Django Queryset: Check if parent model has a child/referring model

Tags: python, django

Models:

```
class Parent(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20L)

class Child(models.Model)
  parent_id = models.ForeignKey('Parent')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
```

**How to get the list of parents that have a child?**

My current solution now is by iterating the Parent-queryset then check if it has a child. Is there any clean solution about this query?

Thanks guys!

Comment: you should use django-mptt for this http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/index.html

Comment: Could you include some more detail about what the query should do? Isn't totally clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @robjohncox I just wanted to get the list of parents that have a child.

Comment: Cool - looks like a couple of good answers below. One thing you should probably change the name of the attribute `parent_id` to `parent` - otherwise you could end up with strange statements like `parent_id_id` or `parent_id.id` if ever referring to the parent objects id.

Answer (score 3):

```
parentList = Child.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=False).values_list('parent_id', flat=True)

parentList = list(set(parentList))
```

applied set to get Parent only once

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
parents_id_that_have_childs = Child.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=False).values_list('parent_id', flat=True)

parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=list(set(parents_id_that_have_childs)))
```

Let me explain:

in parents_id_that_have_childs you will have a list of unique ids of parents that, obviously, have child objs.

then in you just filter the Parents that have these ids.

parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=list(set(parents_id_that_have_childs)))

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a look to django-mptt.

But regarding your question:

```
parents_with_child = Parent.objects.exclude(child_set=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting django-mptt. I'll check this solutions